# Raspberry pi data training

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am working on object detection using OpenCV with raspberry pi and webcam. Could anyone provide the process of data training for stop sign in raspberry pi?

Answer (score 1):

### The Training Process

*Step 1 : Dataset*

First you need a dataset the size depends on your needs.

*Step 2 : Feature Detection*

The first thing is you cannot train your model using images , you need to extract features and then train your model using those feature for feature extraction in opencv check [this](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/d27/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_feature2d.html) .
You can try different features HoG Features can be used in your case

*Step 3 : The Training*

Now for the training part , I would suggest you use Sklearn over Opencv's implementation of SVM , Knn . Sklearn offers a variety of ML algorithms which can be helpful .

[Machine Learning Opencv](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/de2/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_ml.html)

[Sklearn Supervised Learning Models](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html)